# Android Studio stuck at Gradle build running

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

OS: Mac El Capitain

Android Studio Ver: 2.1.1

It's stuck when trying to do this: `Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :cruiselineSDK:generateDebugSources, :cruiselineSDK:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :cruiselineSDK:mockableAndroidJar, :cruiselineSDK:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]`

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

Comment: This happened to me several times and it was happening because I had installed a firewall that was blocking android studio and java processes. I remember how I could see Android Studio consuming more and more RAM while Gradle was trying to build

Comment: I don't think I have a firewall. It only started happening after I upgraded Android studio and gradle

Comment: Does Gradle has acces to internet? Try offline work and see if it still happens. If there isn't something blocking it could also be that your internet is too slow